# Adding a JPanel to another JPanel adds padding

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

When I add a JPanel to another JPanel, there appears to be a default padding/margin, how do I remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding depends on the layout managers you are using for each of the panels.

For example the default layout manager for a JPanel is a FlowLayout with padding of 5 pixels.

If you don't like the 5 pixels, then change the padding of the FlowLayout. Read the FlowLayout API (or whatever layout manager you are using) for the appropriate method to change.